# Does the Spinoreticular Tract end in Brainstem?

Tags: neurophysiology, neuroanatomy, neurology

According to [this book on Springer](http://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-0-387-79948-3_790) spinoreticular tract is :

> As the name implies, the tract originates in the spinal cord and terminates in the reticular formation (RF) in the brainstem. While most of the fibers appear to terminate in the RF of the medulla and lower pons, some may ascend as far as the midbrain.

But according to [Wikipedia :](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinoreticular_tract)

> The spinoreticular tract is an ascending pathway in the white matter of the spinal cord, positioned closely to the lateral spinothalamic tract. The tract is from spinal cord—to reticular formation— to thalamus.

---

What I am unable to understand is if Wikipedia is true then why do we consider this tract as ending in the brainstem rather than ending in the thalamus?

Also I am getting different information about the location of the origin of spinoreticular fibres,

My [Textbook](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=5yxEAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA700&lpg=PA700&dq=The%20spinoreticular%20fibres%20begin%20from%20the%20spinal%20neurons%20mainly%20in%20lamina%20VII%20(also%20V%20and%20VIII).&source=bl&ots=Dq8fm0MRQf&sig=hMQbaz3mlEOrWbfSNY3X9m83TwE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjp9fCeiPLTAhULQY8KHbKyDgIQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=The%20spinoreticular%20fibres%20begin%20from%20the%20spinal%20neurons%20mainly%20in%20lamina%20VII%20(also%20V%20and%20VIII).&f=false) says:

> The spinoreticular fibres begin from the spinal neurons mainly in lamina VII (also V and VIII).

But [this site](http://braininfo.rprc.washington.edu/centraldirectory.aspx?ID=1713) says:

> The term spinoreticular tract refers to a fiber bundle that arises largely from lamina I, lamina IV and lamina V of the spinal cord.

Which source is correct?

Comment: I'm curious... the Wiki article is identified as needing more citations, so I'm wondering why you are weighing an admittedly incomplete Wiki article against your textbook.

Comment: Sometimes my textbook too gets wrong. Also who is correct in the second part?

Comment: Depends on who you read. One reputable source stated the spinoreticular tract originates from neurons located mainly in contralateral laminae 7–8, the lateral reticulated part of lamina 5. They are also located more sparsely in lamina 1, area 10, and the lateral spinal nucleus. Its axons are myelinated, and the majority cross the midline to ascend in the ventrolateral funiculus, intermingled with spinothalamic fibers. Some spinoreticular tract axons are collateral branches of the spinothalamic tract neurons. Another stated something slightly - very slightly - different.

Comment: Could you please cite the source for further reading?

Comment: In the top 5 f hits on google.

Comment: When will you answer the question about chassignac's tubercle?

Comment: From my previous answer/comment, it should seen obvious when I will answer it. The answer is nowhere written in stone.